# Error del tipo not float, variables enteros

Tags: python, condiciones, float, type

```
def hilo1(L2,INI,FIN):
        oddEvenMerge(L2,INI,FIN)
        print ("procesos: "),L2[1:FIN+1]
       
    
    def OddEvenMerge(L2,INI,FIN):
        t3=Thread(target=oddEvenMerge,args=(L2,INI,FIN))
        t3.start()
        t3.join()
    
    def oddEvenMerge(L2,INI,FIN):
        m=(FIN-INI)+1
        odd=[0 for i in range(int(m/2)+1)]
        even=[0 for i in range(int(m/2)+1)]
        if(m==2):
            if (L2[INI]>L2[FIN]):
                intercambio(L2,INI,FIN)
```

> File "C:\Users\Uriel Morales Flores\Documents\ordenamientoerew.py", line 21, in oddEvenMerge
> if (L2[INI]>L2[FIN]):
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Ya he definido las variables como enteros pero me sigue dando error.

Comment: que lenguaje de programación es? Parece boo

Comment: es python en incluso diria que python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

el problema esta en una parte de el codigo que no estas mostrando pero aun asi es facil de corregir,
como valores de `INI,FIN` le estas pasando datos de typo `float`
es decir,a el llamar a el thread le estas pasando datos con coma flotante,
para que el indice te funciones necesitas transofrmarlo en enteros antes de iterar:
`if (L2[int(INI)]>L2[int(FIN])):`

antes a el hacer la comprobación comprueba si el índice de `L2[numero]` cuando numero tiene decimales, por tanto antes hay que transformarlo en entero : `L2[int(numero)]`